# SpringMVC RequestMapping: Adding .xml to controller path for xml response

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, request-mapping

/pets yields a json response. I'd like to use /pets.xml in order to yield an xml response, while maintaining @RequestMapping("pets") on the controller. I can use

```
@RequestMapping("/index") 
@RequestMapping("/index.xml")
```

as a workaround, but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("pets")
class PetController {
  /*code*/
  @RequestMapping(produces = arrayOf("application/json"))
    fun findPetsJson(): List<PetDto> {
      return petService.findAll()
  }
  // this results in /pets/.xml for the xml response. I'm aiming for /pets.xml
  @RequestMapping(".xml", produces = arrayOf("application/xml"))
    fun findPetsXml(): List<PetDto> {
      return petService.findAll()
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am not a fan of solving this problem with explicit paths but with content negotiation. An older but also current post from spring io https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Comment: Remove the `produces` from your request mapping (or add the `application/xml` to the first one). Both `/pets` and `/pets.xml` will be mapped and content negotiation should do the rest. By default a mapping is created for `/pets` and `/pets.*` when the controller is detected.

Comment: @M.Deinum , thanks, that solved it in a much more elegant way than I hoped for: I can actually remove the 2nd requestmapping and the function altogether - they can be written in just one.  Now I only have to find out how to prioritize between them(which one I get when I use no extension on the path, i.e "/pets", but I'm sure it's easily doable. Please add your comment as a response, seeing that it solved my problem.

Comment: @meistermeier , I will check it out, it seems like something I should know. I'm new to kotlin and spring, so thank you for the useful resource!

Comment: Please add what you figured out as an answer here.. Comments are not exactly easily seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Spring MVC `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` will add multiple mappings for your `@RequestMapping` annotated methods (or classes). It will next to the configured one, add one ending with `.*` so that it will match extensions as well.

So in your case `/pets.xml` is already supported by the `/pets.*` mapping which is created by default. Your `produces` now only limits the accepting requests based on the `Accept` request header.

By default the file extension takes precedence over the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

Having just one function is enough. You just need to add arrayOf("application/json", "application/xml) to it and it produces both (it actually does for both even if you remove it, but it's explicit like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("pets")
class PetController {
  /*code*/
  @RequestMapping(produces = arrayOf("application/json", "application/xml), method = RequestMethod.GET)
    fun findPetsJson(): List<PetDto> {
      return petService.findAll()
  }
}
```

This code allows for interogations at both /pets.json and /pets.xml